# IP addresses and CIDR suffixes

Tags: computer-networks

I'm somewhat confused about IP addresses and subnet masks.
Can a same IPv4 address have two different CIDR suffixes ?
for example 95.100.252.115/28 and 95.100.252.115/26 ?

If not, how is the CIDR suffix determined by the IPv4 address?

Comment: Please edit the question to add a reference to the article you have read about CIDR online.

Answer (score 1):

Yes there can be different suffixes, and the IP absolutely does not determine the suffix. You determine the suffix based on how many other computers you want networked together in that subnet group.